# Find the energy of a discrete time signal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, signal-processing

So we have been given the discrete time signal and we have to compute the energy

$y[n]=(\frac 1 2 )^n u[n] -(-\frac 1 2)^{n-1}u[n-1]$

The answer is supposed to be $\frac {28} {15}$ but i cant seem to go there

From what i know since $\sum _0 ^{N-1} r^k$ if $r < 1 $ = $ \frac 1 {1-r}$
And since E=$\sum x^2[n]$ then we have

E=$\sum x^2[n]= (\frac 1 2 )^{2n} + 2(\frac 1 2 )^n(-\frac 1 2 )^n + (-\frac 1 2 )^{2n}  (\frac 1{(\frac 1 2 )^2})$

And from here i thought we just apply the formulas and thats about it but i cant seem to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
y^2[n]=\left(\frac12\right)^{2n}u[n]+\left(-\frac12\right)^{2n-2}u[n-1]-2\left(\frac12\right)^{n}\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}u[n]u[n-1]
$$
so that
$$
\begin{align*}
E&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty y^2[n]\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac14\right)^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac14\right)^{n-1}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^{n}\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac14\right)^{n}+\color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac14\right)^{n}}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^{n}\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1}\qquad (\color{red}{n-1=i,\,i\leftrightarrow n})\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac14\right)^{n}-\require{cancel}\cancel{2}\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^{n+\cancel{1}}\left(\frac12\right)^{n}(-1)^{n}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad(\color{blue}{n-1=i,\,i\leftrightarrow n})\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac14\right)^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^{n}\\
&=2\cdot\frac43-\frac45=\boxed{\frac{28}{15}}
\end{align*}
$$
using $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$, for $|x|<1$.